# How do I define default permissions for users in Django Guardian?

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-guardian

When I create a user in Django, he has no permissions:

```
In [7]: u = User.objects.create(username='aoeu')
In [12]: u.user_permissions.all()
Out[12]: []
```

I want some permissions to be set by default (say, 'api.add_item'), and I use [Django Guardian](http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/). Is this possible to do in a declarative way, eg. without writing a post_save signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
Check django.contrib.auth code to ensure

Comment: Start from models.py, User, Permission and UserManager. As far as I see there are no special hooks to set up predefined permissions when new user created.