# Django default user permissions

Tags: python, django, user-permissions

Is it possible to give a user default permissions for a specific app, right after creation?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312931/how-do-i-define-default-permissions-for-users-in-django-guardian), but since it is 1,5 years old I hope, there is a possibility to do it now.

The background is the following:

I only run one app in my Djangopage. Let's call it 'foo'.
My users log into the admin-page with their LDAP Account. If they log in the first time, their account isn't in the database and will be created. 
When they are logged in then, they can't do anything, because they don't have any permissions. 
I want to give them all permissions for my 'foo' App, right after account-creation. At the moment, I need to log in with an adminaccount and grant them manually.

Comment: an important difference with that question is if you are ok to use post_save signal. The answer was: it is not possible to do it in a *declarative way*, not impossible at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [`RemoteUserBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user) authentication backend with LDAP, then you could subclass it, override the [`configure_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/auth-remote-user/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend.configure_user) method and set the permission there.

If you're using a different method to authenticate, then you can use the `post_save` signal.

Comment: I actually use RemoteUser with LDAP Combined. I will try it